# How to create LXC templates?

Tags: templates, documentation, lxc

I am trying to create an LXC template but I cannot find any documentation on what commands and options the script minimally needs to support.  Is this in fact documented somewhere?  The built-in templates seem rather complex and figuring out what I need to support is difficult.